# Issue in Corda testnet using azure marketplace

Tags: corda

I was using corda opensource 3.2 in azure marketplace by following the instructions given in the
link : https://docs.corda.net/head/testnet-explorer-corda.html . And I am able to connect to the corda testnet via node explorer but I couldnt initiate a transaction because the issuer drop-down was not working. I have shared the screenshots below. And in transaction type only Pay option was there. What could be the issues?. can someone help me on this pls 
[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your node is not set up as an issuer of cash. Have you followed step 4 in the instructions?

> Run the following to create a config file for the finance CorDapp:
>
> echo "issuableCurrencies : [ USD ]" >
>   /opt/corda/cordapps/config/corda-finance--corda.conf

Comment: Yes I did step 4. Initially there were no config folder inside cordapps then i created one and executed Step 4.

Comment: I have made slight changes in the node config file   "issuableCurrencies=[
   USD
] " Now its working

Comment: JK - Just by adding that extra space?

Comment: just replaced issuableCurrencies : [ USD ] with issuableCurrencies = [ USD ]